# How to install DPpackage in R on Mac?

Tags: r, r-package, cran, installation-package

I was trying to install DPpackage in R using
install.packages("DPpackage"). However, it fails with

> Warning in install.packages :
> package ‘DPpackage’ is not available for this version of R.
> Then I tried to check which version of R would work, but I was struggling understand the following output.
> [image]

I then tried

```
install.packages("https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/DPpackage/DPpackage_1.1-7.tar.gz", repos=NULL, type="source")
```

And I got the following error message:

> make: /opt/R/arm64/bin/gfortran: No such file or directory
> make: *** [BDPdensity.o] Error 1
> ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘DPpackage’. removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2-arm64/Resources/library/DPpackage’

Could anyone help with installing the package?

Comment: I think that this is telling you that you need to install `gfortran`  before this package can install and run. I would try that first. Try using this https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/GFortranBinariesMacOS and then reinstalling

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I guess there might be other issues. I've installed `gfortran` following your link, but the same problem showed up when I reinstall it.

Comment: Did you restart rStudio?

You may also need to do some tuning. things used to be easier, but you can try following this tutorial to troubleshoot the install to be sure R can see it
https://www.cynkra.com/blog/2021-03-16-gfortran-macos/

Comment: Yes, I restarted it before trying to reinstall, but the problem still exists. I also contacted the package developer and he said I need to change to an older version of R. (I'm using the latest version now.) I tried 4.2.1 but it still couldn't work. May I ask how do I check which version could work well with the particular package? Cheers.

Comment: if you look in the vignette for the package (usually you can find it by hitting google with DPpackage) it should say that, and it may actually say it somewhere in the error.

Comment: looks like it only says greater than, but nothing about the upper limit. I would look for the date of the last publication http://cran.nexr.com/web/packages/DPpackage/index.html and then use a version of R two or three back from that date